# Clojure JDBC error with Oracle... java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: oracle, jdbc, clojure, ora-00900

In Oracle's SQL developer, I have created a table named BBS_COUNT_BASES with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE BBS_COUNT_BASES
   (    BASE_COUNT NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    BASE_EDN CLOB NOT NULL
   )
```

I have also inserted a record into the table using the statement:

```
INSERT INTO BBS_COUNT_BASES (base_count, base_edn ) VALUES (100, '{}')
```

Now, using SQL Developer, I can use the statement

```
UPDATE BBS_COUNT_BASES SET base_edn = '{}' WHERE base_count = 100
```

to update the base_edn value to (in this test case) the same value.

However, when I attempt to pass this statement to clojure.java.jdbc/query, the JDBC driver errors out with the error shown in the title.  Does anyone have any clue why this statement is being seen as invalid by the JDBC driver?

Comment: 1. Can you paste your Clojure code please? 2. Can you make sure you using the same schema (user) connecting to Oracle through your Clojure program that you use in SQL Developer? I know, it sounds trivial, but have been bitten by this.

Comment: Hold on, you are trying to issue UPDATE through `query`? That will not work, you need to use `update!`. Please confirm that `query` is what you are using in you Clojure program - then that's the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot issue an `UPDATE` statement using `query`. JDBC segregates queries and updates in its interface, that's the meaning of the exception you are getting. Use `clojure.java.jdbc/update!`